# How to import a GraphML DB in embedded Neo4J with Java?

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, graphml

Is it possible to import a database as GraphML XML-File in embedded Neo4j with Java? 
I tried to run the following script but without any success:

```
g.loadGraphML('graphMlFileLocation')
```

I'm unable to use the Script-Engine described [here](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java)

Is there another way to import GraphML XML-Files?

Best Regards Max.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via Java by using GraphMLReader

http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.3.0/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/util/io/graphml/GraphMLReader.html

Comment: But I cannot import the GraphML in an existing Neo4J Graph, can I?